# How to add function in angular

Tags: angular, bulma

Trying to code basic navbar in Angular   but angular code is not executing it says  ERROR TypeError: _co.toggleNavbar is not a function.

```html
<a #navBurger (click)="toggleNavbar()" role="button"  class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

and my function :

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent  {

  @ViewChild('navBurger') navBurger: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('navMenu') navMenu: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.navBurger.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active');
    this.navMenu.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active');
  }
}
```

Comment: did you define it under declarations in your module?  and where do you use appNavigation component in markup

Comment: Is this markup defined in navigation.component.html ?

Comment: Thank you for answer, I solve my problem.